# Angular - Cannot add property xxxx, object is not extensible

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I Use Typescript (Angular) And I have this error: `Cannot add property media, object is not extensible`

I want add a Media element in My step Object. At the origine Step object do not contain any Media array.

```
export interface Step {
  duration: string;
  instructions: string;
  ingredients_instructions?: string;
  ingredients?: Quantity[];
  media?: Media[];
  action?: CookingAction;
}

export interface Media {
  id: string;
  author: string;
  license: string;
  creation_date: string;
  modification_date: string;
  bytes: string;
}

stepsSelection: Step[] = [];
...
const media = {} as Media;
media.bytes = 'foo';
media.license = 'DR';
this.stepsSelection[i].media = [ ];
this.stepsSelection[i].media[0] = media;
```

Comment: My problem come from @ngrx (not typeScript).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
this.stepsSelection[i] = {};    
this.stepsSelection[i]['media'] = [];
this.stepsSelection[i].media[0] = media;
```

Comment: this.stepsSelection[i] = {};     =>    impossible assigne {} to Step type

Comment: Yes because when you create your object you don't respect your interface. You declare some mandatory variiable. Put *?* to all your variables in *Step* and *Media* interface and it will work. Or if you want to keep them, you need to pass them when you assign an object to a *Step[]* type. Don't know if my explanation is clear

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add properties to the object on the fly, you can modify your interface like that

```
export interface Step {
  duration: string;
  instructions: string;
  ingredients_instructions?: string;
  ingredients?: Quantity[];
  action?: CookingAction;
  [prop: string]: any;
}

const step = {} as Step;
const media = {} as Media;
step.media = [ media ];
step.foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: sorry, but I do not want modify Step interface (is not my project)

Comment: Try this then:
    stepsSelection[i] = <Step> {
       media: [ media ]
    };

Comment: Also, this is not a good solution. It lets you add any object. You will lose all the benefits of strict typing...